# Escape backslash in Angular for the http post call on GraphQL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, graphql

I am trying to save some data using GraphQL which contains backslash in its input in my Angular 5 app.
For example, while creating a table I want to keep table name as **Indian\Cars**

Below is the body of HTTP post call:

```
{"query":"mutation { createTable(input:[{name:\"Indian\Cars\"}]) { id } }"}
```

**Note: name is a string that's the reason I have added \"\" to escape.**

But GraphQL is throwing an error:

**'SyntaxError: Unexpected token \' in JSON**

I have tried with replacing it. The table name can be anything, an input from UI.So according to that, I am building the HTTP Post call body dynamically as below.

```
createGraphQLBodyObjectForPostCall(tableName) {

  const newTableName = tableName.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');

  const bodyObject = {"query":"mutation { createTable(input:[{name:\\"' + newTableName + '\\"}]) { id } }"};

  return bodyObject;
}
```

but I want to create the table with the exact same name as **Indian\Cars**
I just want to escape it from the HTTP post-call, but in DB it must save the exact input that we are sending.

Comment: Did you try: `{"query":"mutation { createTable(input:[{name:\"Indian\\Cars\"}]) { id } }"}`

Comment: You can also try {"query":"mutation{createTable(input:[{name:'Indian\\Cars'}]){id}}"}. Check the link: https://www.unserialize.com/s/2415ff6d-890e-a829-1397-000027c4f16e

Comment: @AkshayM I need to construct the post-call body dynamically, in the service, before I do an API call. Yes, If I add Indian\\Cars will work, but how to achieve it from the service as I mentioned.